# Typecasting a Double value to Int64 in Swift, number of digits is 13, but the system that its running on is a 32 bit system, would it fail?

Tags: swift, cpu-architecture

I am trying to typecast a Double value to Int64 in Swift language, number of digits is 13 or more after getting final Int, it runs fine in a 64 bit system, but what happens if the system that it's running on is a 32 bit system?

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference: A `Double` is a 64-bit floating point number, and an `Int64` is a 64-bit signed integer – no matter if the code is compiled for a 32-bit or a 64-bit platform.

Platform-dependent types are for example `Int` and `CGFloat`.